# Как заменить значения для всех выбранных результатов?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Вот таким запросом я могу выбрать названия всех таблиц и их полей, которые ссылаются на таблицу `mytable`

```sql
SELECT 
  tc.table_name,
  kcu.column_name

FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc

LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
  ON tc.constraint_catalog = kcu.constraint_catalog
  AND tc.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
  AND tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name

LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
  ON tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog
  AND tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema
  AND tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name

INNER JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
  ON rc.unique_constraint_catalog = ccu.constraint_catalog
  AND rc.unique_constraint_schema = ccu.constraint_schema
  AND rc.unique_constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name

WHERE  lower(tc.constraint_type) in ('foreign key')   and ccu.table_name = 'mytable';
```

Как мне заменить все значения, которые ссылаются, например на id 1 в таблице `mytable`, чтобы они стали ссылаться на id 2?

Comment: Сгенерировать динамический запрос по всем таблицам, используя ваш запрос выше.

update some_dyn_table
SET MyTableId = 2
WHERE MyTableId = 1

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать процедурное расширение `PL/pgSQL`:

```sql
DO
$$
  DECLARE r record;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN 
      SELECT tc.table_name
           , kcu.column_name
        FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
              LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
                ON tc.constraint_catalog = kcu.constraint_catalog
               AND tc.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
               AND tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
              LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints AS rc
                ON tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog
               AND tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema
               AND tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
             INNER JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
                ON rc.unique_constraint_catalog = ccu.constraint_catalog
               AND rc.unique_constraint_schema = ccu.constraint_schema
               AND rc.unique_constraint_name = ccu.constraint_name
       WHERE lower(tc.constraint_type) IN ('foreign key')
         AND ccu.table_name = 't'
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || r.table_name || ' SET ' || r.column_name ||
        ' = 2 WHERE ' || r.column_name || ' = 1';
    END LOOP;
  END;
$$;
```

Comment: А как в блоке `LOOP` у `r` появляются названия полей? `table_name` и  `column_name` - где мы задаем эти названия?

Comment: Я пытаюсь в `LOOP` сделать вот так и получаю пустой ответ `EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || r.column_name || ' FROM ' || r.table_name;`

Comment: Вы на тестовой базе мой запрос выполнить пробовали?  У меня всё работает.

Comment: Запрос с селектом? Да, пробовал. Выбирается пустой ответ (

Comment: Нет.  Запрос, который я указал в ответе.  Вы занимаетесь странными вещами.  Зачем вам результаты `SELECT`?  https://pastebin.com/W0YzM79B.